# Record audio separatedly

Tags: audio-recording, sync

I want to record a music scene live, and I will be recording the audio of the event properly, for quality audio production. I also want to produce a video of it using that audio after it has been produced. So, just to clarify, I don't want to connect my audio recording equipment to the video camera while filming, I just don't care what audio the camera gets, I will drop it.

My question is, what do I need to do while recording, or while editing, to get the perfect sync between the audio and video of the same event from the two different sources?

Thanks!

Comment: JoshP, thanks for moderating, but this question is actually the opposite to the one you suggest as duplicated, for which I'm also the OP. The other one is about sync segments (different scenes) of unrelated video over an audio track. This one is about making sure that the audio and video of the same recording are in sync when captured separatedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historically, the answer to this was to use a timecode generator and genlock your camera and audio gear.  Decent quality modern equipment however(like $300+ range audio recorders), has accurate enough internal time code that doing a simple clapper at the start and end to sync on should be sufficient.  As long as you don't get dropped frames, things should stay in sync very closely and in the unlikely event that there is an issue, you can stretch it between the beginning and end sync points to get good results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe Premiere. Pro CC, or if you are using other versions,you can get other specific plugins and then you can follow their tutorial and you will have the perfect sync. I think that NeatVideo is what you need. (I don't clearly remember if it is that plugin since I haven't used it for a long time)